# Check for user logged-in or not in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

If user enter a URL then my application check that user session expire or not and user logged-in or not, if session expire or user not logged-in then my application redirect to "Login"-controller's  "Index"-method.(I have 4 controllers and 8-9 Action Methods in each controller, please suggest me a convenient/simple way to do this)
How can I do this ?

Comment: And your question is?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Authorize` attribute for Actions that need the user to be logged in.

Example:

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult DoSomething()
{
   //code here...
}
```

Userts that are not authorized will be redirected to login page that you have set up in Web.config.

Comment: When I use code like below :
[Authorize]
public ActionResult ManageUsers()
{
    //code
}
It says 401-unauthorized if I am going with login or without, in both conditions.

Comment: How can I set this [Authorize] attribute in my login section ?? please suggest

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
//user not logged in
if (Session["User"] == null)
    {
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
    //send the user to login page with return URL
    filterContext.Result =
        new RedirectToRouteResult(new System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary {{ "controller", "Login" },
        { "action", "Index" },
        { "returnUrl",    filterContext.HttpContext.Request.RawUrl } });
    return;
}
```

This code will add your last access url in your redirected URL, So you can go back same page after login.

Comment: Create your custom attribute, add this code inside that. Add Attribute on Action.